# In Borderlands 2, what is the stealth aspect of Zero?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just bought Borderlands 2 and I started with Zero and I noticed he uses a sword as his melee (duh) and I know he is supposed to be an assassin but does he have a special backstab ability or a stealth mode? Or is he just a play-style that requires sniper-rifles and long range?

Comment: Did you open Skill Tree?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see the point if his stealth mode only lasts 15 seconds

Comment: Well, this is his "stealth aspect". If you expect him to sneak around eneny lines a la Splinter Cell, then you're thinking about the wrong game. Borderlands is a fast-paced shooter, and you are supposed to hold the trigger down and dart around the battlefield. In this context, vanishing from view for six (it's not even 15) seconds every 15 seconds is a great amount of stealth.

Comment: Okay, let us rephrase :-) Zer0 is not about stealth, he is about being able to dodge some damage, reposition, and deal devastating critical blows :-)

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that since he is an assassin that he could sneak around and flank enemies or even sneak up behind an enemy an d back stab him

Comment: He, indeed, can sneak up on enemies and deal bonus damage with skills like *Backstab* and *Ambush*. But all this "sneaking up" happens in seconds in form of mad dashes in the middle of gunfight :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stealth aspect of Zero comes from his Action Skill: *Decepti0n*

Each hero has an ability called an *Action Skill*, which is a 'mode' or friendly drop (such as a sentry turret) unique to that character that lasts a few seconds. It can be activated at any time once unlocked (at Level 5) and has a cooldown before using it again.

---

Zero's action skill is a cloaking ability that also grants bonuses to damage. It has a cooldown of 15 seconds

From the [Borderlands Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Zer0):

> Action Skill: Decepti0n
>
> "Decepti0n" grants Zer0 the ability to deploy a holographic decoy of himself and enter an invisible "stealth mode." While cloaked, he can maneuver about the battlefield dealing amplified damage on his next attack. The longer Zer0 stays cloaked, the more damage he can inflict to enemies; however, the shorter Zer0 stays cloaked, the sooner he is able to use the skill again. Zer0 does not enter a separate dimension like Lilith when she Phasewalks, and can still take damage from all sources while cloaked.

Damage Benefits whilst in Decepti0n:

- +650% Melee Damage
- +200% Gun Damage / +250% Gun Critical Hit Damage.

Answer (score 1):

The Decepti0n action skill works well for a semi-stealth prime character.

If you max out your *Bloodshed* tree fully, the last tier gives you the ability to redeploy a second time and a third, a fourth and so on for every consecutive kill you get while in Decepti0n.

There is also the *Backstab* skill about midway down the tree that increases your melee damage while attacking an enemy from behind, combine that with the *Execute* skill that allows you to dash a few feet to your enemy whilst in Decpti0n and you've got a pretty kickass invisible stalker.

I was able to exploit this character build to have Decepti0n last a good 50 seconds while in a circle of slaughter, while my allies drilled down the enemies health I came in for finishing blows.